# upload file in azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload the file that I have stored in MemoryStream using the following code.

```
        private static void SaveStream(MemoryStream stream, string fileName)
        {
            var blobStorageService = new BlobStorageService();
            UploadBlob(stream, fileName);
        }

        public void UploadBlob(MemoryStream fileStream,string fileName)
        {
            var blobContainer = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(Environment
                               .GetEnvironmentVariable("ContainerName"));
            var blobClient = blobContainer.GetBlobClient(fileName);
            blobClient.Upload(fileStream);  <--- Error Message

        }
```

Error Message: System.ArgumentException: 'content.Position must be less than content.Length.Please set content.Position to the start of the data to upload.'

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This happened because the current position is at the end of the stream. You can set the position to the start of the stream before uploading

```
var blobClient = blobContainer.GetBlobClient(fileName);
fileStream.Position =0;
blobClient.Upload(fileStream)
```

Comment: It might be worth explaining what is wrong with OP's code (i.e. why they are getting that message). :)

Comment: I wouldn't mind a refresher on that myself.

Comment: Explaining in layman's term : Stream is a one way data structure, when you read stream character by character, it's position starts moving forward.
So if you have a code that has read the entire fileStream then it's position will be moved to the end.
When you try to perform upload of fileStream - it's already read till the last character, so the uploader will throw an exception saying that there's nothing further to read.
In order to solve this - we manually set the fileStream's position to the 0th position, hence the fileStream is again fresh to be read.

And that's why the upload works!